# How to display al the contents of a method using JSONValue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The following code gives the result of the methods which I am calling individually.

My actual requirement is that I want to call just a particular method, for example a `Loan` method, and it should display all the contents in this method.

So what changes should I make in the code below?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    [connection release];  

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.dataWebService = nil;

    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*) [responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"]; 

    [responseString release];    

    NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];

    //fetch the data

    NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];
    NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
    float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

    NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

    //set the text to the label

    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ \n \n country:  %@ \n \n amount $%.2f", name,country,outstandingAmout ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you right but if you want to just use a method such as

```
NSString * loanString = [self stringFromLoan:[latestLoans objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Do this:

```
-(NSString*)stringFromLoan:(NSDictionary*)loan{

    NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];

    NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];

    float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

    NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ \n \n country:  %@ \n \n amount $%.2f", name,country,outstandingAmout];
}
```

So your code would look like this:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.dataWebService = nil;


    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*) [responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"]; 

    [responseString release];    

    NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];

    label.numberOfLines = 0;

    label.text = [self stringFromLoan:loan];
}
```

PS.

Don't release the connection it is autoreleased.

Comment: thank u yup it works..my question was without writing a method string loan...just calling a method"loan" and cant we fetch all the data present in "loan method" i dont wan to write separate method u just wan to fetch contents in "loan method" from responsestring....

Answer (score 0):

UITableviewController can be used for displaying the contents of the NSArray object.

Comment: ok wat changes in code?i shd drag tableview in UI and wat i shd change in code?